# "return this" inside a constructor definition: what is its role?

Tags: javascript

```
// Q returns new Library object
    var Q = function (params) {
        return new Library(params);
    };

    // In our Library we get our selector with querySelectorAll (we do not support < ie8)
    // We also add selector length, version and twitter/github or whatever you like as information about your library.
    var Library = function (params) {
        // Get params
        var selector = document.querySelectorAll(params),
            i = 0;
        // Get selector length
        this.length = selector.length;
        this.version = '0.1.0';
        this.twitter = 'http://www.twitter.com/mmmmm_';

        // Add selector to object for method chaining
        for (; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i] = selector[i];
        }

        // Return as object
        return this;        
    };
```

Why we have `return this;` at the end of the constructor? What happens if we omit it?

It's not the first time that I find this instruction inside a constructor but sometimes it appears, sometimes (in other classes of other scripts) it doesn't appear and I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Return current object from the function.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the constructor is invoked with the `new Ctor()` syntax, there is no difference if you write `return this` or not. If the constructor reached the end without returning anything it implicitly returns `this`.

If you invoke the constructor as a regular function without using `new` then its going to behave as usual: functions that reach the end without getting to a return statement return `undefined` and a `return this` statement will depend on what was the value of the `this` that got passed in (it will depend on how you call the function).

Answer (score 1):

It returns the current object instance, which allows you to do method-chaining (e.g. `object.method1().method2().method3();`)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It was specifically about the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's there so you can chain multiple function on the same object. jQuery does it everywhere.